# How to remove an environment variable on OSX using bash

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, path

I'm running under Snow Leopard 10.6.8 and I recently added an environment variable which it seems to be messing my bash terminal (I guess).

What I did is add the variable `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.2/lib` to my .bash_profile file, which looks like this:

```
export PATH=/Users/Carlos/pear/bin:$PATH:/Users/Carlos/android-sdks/platforms:/Users/Carlos/android-sdks/platforms-tools:/Library/PostgreSQL/9.2/bin/
# Setting PATH for Python 2.7
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.2/lib
```

And then run the command:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

So that now I can see the variable listed along with all the environment variables when I run "set" on the terminal.

The thing is I want to remove it. I've checked several forums and to be honest none of the solutions worked for me so far.

Comment: Aside from the correct answer by mmmmmm, think of **why** you had defined the variable in the first place - you must have had a reason for it. I don't know whether the variable makes sense for you productive environment (i.e. using postgresql), but it should not influence or damage your Terminal in any way. Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146274/is-it-ok-to-use-dyld-library-path-on-mac-os-x-and-whats-the-dynamic-library-s) about this variable.

Answer (score 197, accepted):

unset it

```
unset DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

The [bash reference manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameters) says

> Once a variable is set, it may be unset only by using the unset builtin command.

Comment: If you have saved variable in ~/.bash_profile then you need to delete it from there. For example with: `nano ~/.bash_profile`